# Making a mouse handler in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader, osdev

I'm writing an Operating System in NASM assembly and I have a problem making a mouse handler (POINTING DEVICE BIOS INTERFACE handler). I've tried searching the internet on how to do it, but I had no success.

Here is the code that sets things up:

```
call checkPS2 ;PS2 routines
jc NOMOUSE
call enablePS2
jc NOMOUSE
```

These are the PS2 functions:

```
;PS2 mouse routines
NOMOUSE:
    ;Prompt error
ret

checkPS2:
    int 11h         ; get equipment list
    test al, 3
    jz  noPS2       ; jump if PS/2-Mouse not indicated
    mov  bh,3
    mov  ax, 0C205h
    int 15h             ; initialize mouse, bh=datasize
    jc noPS2
    mov bh,3
    mov ax, 0C203h
    int 15h             ; set mouse resolution bh
    jc noPS2
    mov ax, cs
    mov es, ax
    mov bx, PS2dummy
    mov ax, 0C207h
    int 15h             ; mouse, es:bx=ptr to handler
    jc noPS2
    xor bx, bx
    mov es, bx      ; mouse, es:bx=ptr to handler
    mov ax, 0C207h
    int 15h
ret

noPS2:
    stc
ret

PS2dummy:
retf

enablePS2:
    call disablePS2
    mov ax, cs
    mov es, ax
    mov bx, IRQhandler
    mov ax, 0C207h  ; es:bx=ptr to handler
    int 15h
    mov bh,1        ; set mouse on
    mov ax, 0C200h
    int 15h
ret

disablePS2:
    xor bx, bx      ; set mouse off
    mov ax, 0C200h
    int 15h
    xor bx, bx
    mov es, bx
    mov ax, 0C207h  ; es:bx=ptr to handler
    int 15h
ret

IRQhandler:
    ;assume  ds:nothing,es:nothing
    cld
    push ds
    push es
    pusha
    mov ax, cs
    mov ds, ax
    mov bp,sp
    mov al,[bp+24+6]    ; buttons
    mov bl,al
    shl al,3        ; CF=Y sign bit
    sbb ch,ch       ; signed extension 9->16 bit
    cbw         ; extend X sign bit
    mov al,[bp+24+4]    ; AX=X movement
    mov cl,[bp+24+2]    ; CX=Y movement
    xchg bx,ax
    neg cx              ; reverse Y movement
    popa
    pop es
    pop ds
retf
```

The loop that calls those functions:

```
mov ax, 0xc209 ;Reads from the mouse
int 15h        ;-||- 
mov dl, bl ;first byte(bl)
mov bl, 02h ;Color Green
call printhex ;prints dl in hex


mov ax, 0xc209 ;Reads from the mouse
int 15h        ;-||- 
mov dl, cl ;second byte(bl)
mov bl, 02h ;Color Green
call printhex ;prints dl in hex

mov ax, 0xc209 ;Reads from the mouse
int 15h        ;-||-
mov bl, 02h ;Color Green
call printhex ;prints dl(3rd byte read)
```

The first thing I noticed was that there were numerous white pixels on the screen that just came up randomly.

The code should just give the location of the mouse while the mouse cursor should remains hidden. I had already tested my `printhex` function and I know that it worked and the numbers I saw were:

```
0x02
0x00
0x00
```

When I moved the mouse none of the values changed. The configurations I had was VirtualBox with a PS/2 mouse.

Comment: I'm in graphics mode

Comment: now x=0x00 and y=0x00 :(

Comment: while I move the mouse

Comment: Yes it is a bootloader

Comment: No I did not post this as another user

Comment: I was just curious, someone was asking about bootloaders / real mode  / mouse etc using text mode earlier in the month in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54042732/how-to-move-cursor-with-mouse  .I happened to make a comment that pointed to some rudimentary code for using Int 15/ax=C2xx to produce a text mode cursor (not graphics). http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/stackoverflow/54042732/ (stage2.asm contains the useful code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide a complete example, however I finally had some time to look at this. One of the the primary issues is that [Int 15h/AX=0C209h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1605.htm) is an optional feature. There is a note in RBIL that says

> Note: IBM classifies this function as optional

I discovered that on a number of emulators (QEMU, BOCHs, VirtualBox) that this BIOS function doesn't seem to be implemented. Calling it won't yield the data you are looking for. You can use the mouse handler to read the X and Y movement and status byte and update global variables that your main routine can poll. Your mouse handler `IRQhandler` is not really an IRQ handler, but a FAR function that the BIOS mouse interrupt handler will call. You have some existing code in that handler that retrieves the X and Y movement but doesn't do anything with it. If you maintain a couple of global variables for X and Y and add the movement values to them you can maintain the absolute coordinates that can be queried by your main loop. You can also create a global variable to store the status byte that is read.

Using your code as a template I generated this simple bootloader that tests this code. The bootloader contains a [BIOS Parameter Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_parameter_block) in case you intend to boot from [USB using Floppy Disk Emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47320115/3857942) on real hardware. It can be removed if it isn't needed. I also provide some routines to display unsigned bytes and words in hexadecimal. The video mode can be adjusted, but I used Mode 13h (320x200x256) as a default:

**bpb.inc**:

```
global bpb_disk_info

    jmp boot_start
    TIMES 3-($-$$) DB 0x90   ; Support 2 or 3 byte encoded JMPs before BPB.

bpb_disk_info:
    ; Dos 4.0 EBPB 1.44MB floppy
    OEMname:           db    "mkfs.fat"  ; mkfs.fat is what OEMname mkdosfs uses
    bytesPerSector:    dw    512
    sectPerCluster:    db    1
    reservedSectors:   dw    1
    numFAT:            db    2
    numRootDirEntries: dw    224
    numSectors:        dw    2880
    mediaType:         db    0xf0
    numFATsectors:     dw    9
    sectorsPerTrack:   dw    18
    numHeads:          dw    2
    numHiddenSectors:  dd    0
    numSectorsHuge:    dd    0
    driveNum:          db    0
    reserved:          db    0
    signature:         db    0x29
    volumeID:          dd    0x2d7e5a1a
    volumeLabel:       db    "NO NAME    "
    fileSysType:       db    "FAT12   "
```

**boot.asm**:

```
HW_EQUIP_PS2     equ 4          ; PS2 mouse installed?
MOUSE_PKT_BYTES  equ 3          ; Number of bytes in mouse packet
MOUSE_RESOLUTION equ 3          ; Mouse resolution 8 counts/mm

VIDEO_MODE       equ 0x13

bits 16
cpu 8086
ORG 0x7c00

; Include a BPB (1.44MB floppy with FAT12) to be more compatible with USB floppy media
%include "bpb.inc"

boot_start:
    xor ax, ax                  ; DS=SS=ES=0
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax                  ; Stack at 0x0000:0x7c00
    mov sp, 0x7c00
    cld                         ; Set string instructions to use forward movement

    ; FAR JMP to ensure set CS to 0
    jmp 0x0000:.setcs
.setcs:

    mov ax, VIDEO_MODE
    int 0x10                    ; Set video mode

    call mouse_initialize
    jc .no_mouse                ; If CF set then error, inform user and end
    call mouse_enable           ; Enable the mouse

    sti
.main_loop:
    hlt                         ; Halt processor until next interrupt
    call poll_mouse             ; Poll mouse and update display with coordintes & status
    jmp .main_loop              ; Endless main loop

.no_mouse:
    mov si, noMouseMsg          ; Error enabling mouse
    call print_string           ; Display message and enter infinite loop

.err_loop:
    hlt
    jmp .err_loop

; Function: mouse_initialize
;           Initialize the mouse if present
;
; Inputs:   None
; Returns:  CF = 1 if error, CF=0 success
; Clobbers: AX

mouse_initialize:
    push es
    push bx

    int 0x11                    ; Get equipment list
    test ax, HW_EQUIP_PS2       ; Is a PS2 mouse installed?
    jz .no_mouse                ;     if not print error and end

    mov ax, 0xC205              ; Initialize mouse
    mov bh, MOUSE_PKT_BYTES     ; 3 byte packets
    int 0x15                    ; Call BIOS to initialize
    jc .no_mouse                ;    If not successful assume no mouse

    mov ax, 0xC203              ; Set resolution
    mov bh, MOUSE_RESOLUTION    ; 8 counts / mm
    int 0x15                    ; Call BIOS to set resolution
    jc .no_mouse                ;    If not successful assume no mouse

    push cs
    pop es                      ; ES = segment where code and mouse handler reside

    mov bx, mouse_callback_dummy
    mov ax, 0xC207              ; Install a default null handler (ES:BX)
    int 0x15                    ; Call BIOS to set callback
    jc .no_mouse                ;    If not successful assume no mouse

    clc                         ; CF=0 is success
    jmp .finished
.no_mouse:
    stc                         ; CF=1 is error
.finished:
    pop bx
    pop es
    ret

; Function: mouse_enable
;           Enable the mouse
;
; Inputs:   None
; Returns:  None
; Clobbers: AX

mouse_enable:
    push es
    push bx

    call mouse_disable          ; Disable mouse before enabling

    push cs
    pop es
    mov bx, mouse_callback
    mov ax, 0xC207              ; Set mouse callback function (ES:BX)
    int 0x15                    ; Call BIOS to set callback

    mov ax, 0xC200              ; Enable/Disable mouse
    mov bh, 1                   ; BH = Enable = 1
    int 0x15                    ; Call BIOS to disable mouse

    pop bx
    pop es
    ret

; Function: mouse_disable
;           Disable the mouse
;
; Inputs:   None
; Returns:  None
; Clobbers: AX

mouse_disable:
    push es
    push bx

    mov ax, 0xC200              ; Enable/Disable mouse
    xor bx, bx                  ; BH = Disable = 0
    int 0x15                    ; Call BIOS to disable mouse

    mov es, bx
    mov ax, 0xC207              ; Clear callback function (ES:BX=0:0)
    int 0x15                    ; Call BIOS to set callback

    pop bx
    pop es
    ret

; Function: mouse_callback (FAR)
;           called by the interrupt handler to process a mouse data packet
;           All registers that are modified must be saved and restored
;           Since we are polling manually this handler does nothing
;
; Inputs:   SP+4  = Unused (0)
;           SP+6  = MovementY
;           SP+8  = MovementX
;           SP+10 = Mouse Status
;
; Returns:  None
; Clobbers: None

ARG_OFFSETS      equ 6          ; Offset of args from BP

mouse_callback:
    push bp                     ; Function prologue
    mov bp, sp
    push ds                     ; Save registers we modify
    push ax
    push bx
    push cx
    push dx

    push cs
    pop ds                      ; DS = CS, CS = where our variables are stored

    mov al,[bp+ARG_OFFSETS+6]
    mov bl, al                  ; BX = copy of status byte
    mov cl, 3                   ; Shift signY (bit 5) left 3 bits
    shl al, cl                  ; CF = signY
                                ; Sign bit of AL = SignX
    sbb dh, dh                  ; CH = SignY value set in all bits
    cbw                         ; AH = SignX value set in all bits
    mov dl, [bp+ARG_OFFSETS+2]  ; CX = movementY
    mov al, [bp+ARG_OFFSETS+4]  ; AX = movementX

    ; new mouse X_coord = X_Coord + movementX
    ; new mouse Y_coord = Y_Coord + (-movementY)
    neg dx
    mov cx, [mouseY]
    add dx, cx                  ; DX = new mouse Y_coord
    mov cx, [mouseX]
    add ax, cx                  ; AX = new mouse X_coord

    ; Status
    mov [curStatus], bl         ; Update the current status with the new bits
    mov [mouseX], ax            ; Update current virtual mouseX coord
    mov [mouseY], dx            ; Update current virtual mouseY coord

    pop dx                      ; Restore all modified registers
    pop cx
    pop bx
    pop ax
    pop ds
    pop bp                      ; Function epilogue

mouse_callback_dummy:
    retf                        ; This routine was reached via FAR CALL. Need a FAR RET

; Function: poll_mouse
;           Poll the mouse state and display the X and Y coordinates and the status byte
;
; Inputs:   None
; Returns:  None
; Clobbers: None

poll_mouse:
    push ax
    push bx
    push dx

    mov bx, 0x0002              ; Set display page to 0 (BH) and color green (BL)

    cli
    mov ax, [mouseX]            ; Retrieve current mouse coordinates. Disable interrupts
    mov dx, [mouseY]            ; So that these two variables are read atomically
    sti

    call print_word_hex         ; Print the mouseX coordinate
    mov si, delimCommaSpc
    call print_string

    mov ax, dx
    call print_word_hex         ; Print the mouseY coordinate
    mov si, delimCommaSpc
    call print_string

    mov al, [curStatus]
    call print_byte_hex         ; Print the last read mouse state byte

    mov al, 0x0d
    call print_char             ; Print carriage return to return to beginning of line

    pop dx
    pop bx
    pop ax
    ret

; Function: print_string
;           Display a string to the console on the specified page and in a
;           specified color if running in a graphics mode
;
; Inputs:   SI = Offset of address to print
;           BH = Page number
;           BL = foreground color (graphics modes only)
; Clobbers: SI

print_string:
    push ax
    mov ah, 0x0e                ; BIOS TTY Print
    jmp .getch
.repeat:
    int 0x10                    ; print character
.getch:
    lodsb                       ; Get character from string
    test al,al                  ; Have we reached end of string?
    jnz .repeat                 ;     if not process next character
.end:
    pop ax
    ret

; Function: print_char
;           Print character on specified page and in a specified color
;           if running in a graphics mode
;
; Inputs:   AL = Character to print
;           BH = Page number
;           BL = foreground color (graphics modes only)
; Returns:  None
; Clobbers: AX

print_char:
    mov ah, 0x0e                ; TTY function to display character in AL
    int 0x10                    ; Make BIOS call
    ret

; Function: print_word_hex
;           Print a 16-bit unsigned integer in hexadecimal on specified
;           page and in a specified color if running in a graphics mode
;
; Inputs:   AX = Unsigned 16-bit integer to print
;           BH = Page number
;           BL = foreground color (graphics modes only)
; Returns:  None
; Clobbers: Mone

print_word_hex:
    xchg al, ah                 ; Print the high byte first
    call print_byte_hex
    xchg al, ah                 ; Print the low byte second
    call print_byte_hex
    ret

; Function: print_byte_hex
;           Print a 8-bit unsigned integer in hexadecimal on specified
;           page and in a specified color if running in a graphics mode
;
; Inputs:   AL = Unsigned 8-bit integer to print
;           BH = Page number
;           BL = foreground color (graphics modes only)
; Returns:  None
; Clobbers: Mone

print_byte_hex:
    push ax
    push cx
    push bx

    lea bx, [.table]            ; Get translation table address

    ; Translate each nibble to its ASCII equivalent
    mov ah, al                  ; Make copy of byte to print
    and al, 0x0f                ;     Isolate lower nibble in AL
    mov cl, 4
    shr ah, cl                  ; Isolate the upper nibble in AH
    xlat                        ; Translate lower nibble to ASCII
    xchg ah, al
    xlat                        ; Translate upper nibble to ASCII

    pop bx                      ; Restore attribute and page
    mov ch, ah                  ; Make copy of lower nibble
    mov ah, 0x0e
    int 0x10                    ; Print the high nibble
    mov al, ch
    int 0x10                    ; Print the low nibble

    pop cx
    pop ax
    ret
.table: db "0123456789ABCDEF", 0

; Uncomment these lines if not using a BPB (via bpb.inc)
; numHeads:        dw 2         ; 1.44MB Floppy has 2 heads & 18 sector per track
; sectorsPerTrack: dw 18

align 2
mouseX:       dw 0              ; Current mouse X coordinate
mouseY:       dw 0              ; Current mouse Y coordinate
curStatus:    db 0              ; Current mouse status
noMouseMsg:   db "Error setting up & initializing mouse", 0x0d, 0x0a, 0
delimCommaSpc:db ", ", 0

bootDevice:   db 0x00

; Pad boot sector to 510 bytes and add 2 byte boot signature for 512 total bytes
TIMES 510-($-$$) db  0
dw 0xaa55
```

The code can be built into a disk image with:

```
nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin

# Build 1.44MB disk image
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=1024 count=1440
dd if=boot.bin of=disk.img conv=notrunc
```

I'm supplying this code because I can't tell why your code may have been displaying unwanted pixels occasionally. That kind of issue may be related to the code you didn't provide. When run in VirtualBox it should look something like this:
[image]

Comment: When I tried this it worked but can I implement this to my project somehow

Comment: @microcapacitor You should be able to easily integrate it. The real code changes are in the IRQHandler and then the mouse polling routine that pints the values. You just have to make it work with your print functions etc. because you didn't provide an [mcve] in your question I don't know what your project and other code looks like. I presented a completely verifiable example and build instruction to show ho valuable it is to show complete code (in both questions and answers). If you added your complete code and build instructions to your question I would be able to integrate it into your code.

Comment: I just tested this on real hardware and it worked there too. Nice and clear example, thanks.