# Making a serial mouse handler in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, mouse, osdev

I've found [Making a mouse handler in x86 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54280828/making-a-mouse-handler-in-x86-assembly) and the code works in qemu but not in pcem or 86box.  I've noticed that pcem and 86box have the word serial after the device name so I'm assuming that it means serial mouse but how would I interface with it?

Comment: In 86box it's probably easier to choose a [machine type](https://86box.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings/input.html) with a ps/2 port. For a serial mouse you would probably have to [talk the protocol](https://roborooter.com/post/serial-mice/) yourself.

Comment: The problem with that is most of the machines doesn't have a PS/2 option especially the 8086 ones.

Comment: Then some info on how to handle https://wiki.osdev.org/Serial_Ports may be helpful.

Comment: Right I've got the first part sorted as I'm getting 0xAE but I'm a little confused as to how I translate the bytes from the in to the ones in your first link.  Looking at the "Data packet format" part it looks straight forward but looking at the "Graphical representation of a packet" part I'm a little confused.  I've tried testing with and al, 0x01 and and al, 0x40 and both seem to be none zero all the time.

Comment: I've found https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=20 but I'm a little confused as to where the whole INT_0xC comes in cause I can't get anything to happen if I set a handler for that interrupt.